# how to use groupBy in laravel Eloquent in joind query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-relations

i have 4 tables and i want to run this query on this:
state (id, name)
scopes(id, state_id , name)
branches(id,scope_id,name)
query_brancheDailies (id, branche_id ,  date , name , manabe_arzan)

```
State::with(['scopes' => function ($query_state) {
                          $query_state->with(['branches' => function ($query_branche) {
                                $query_branche->with(['brancheDailies' => function ($query_brancheDailies) {
                                         $query_brancheDailies
                                             ->selectRaw('* , sum(manabe_arzan) as new_manabe_arzan')
                                             ->where('date','=', '1399/12/01');
                                    }])->groupBy('branches.scope_id');
                                }]);
                           }])->get();
```

but groupBy not correctly worked !!
i dnot know correct place for it

please help me..

Comment: Can you add explanation for *but groupBy not correctly worked !!* what is the actual problem are you not getting the desired results or invalid result for sum expression?

Answer (score 1):

maybe this example work for u

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->groupBy('first_name', 'status')
                ->having('account_id', '>', 100)
                ->get();
```

can you check more here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#grouping
here in the url can you find more example